# How can I connect Ember.JS with a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, sqlite

I'd like to connect **Ember.JS** to a **persistent** datasource.

**Ember.JS** could manage the main parts of the application. **Express.JS** could assist to fetch data and save Ember.JS's app data in a database.

I've heard of **stores**, **models** and **adapters**... Honest, it confuses me a lot!

Could anyone explain the ways of connecting Ember to a database (maybe sqlite3)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember.js is a web framework and is not really intended to be connected to a database directly. You should build an API (with express.js and node for example), and connect this API to your database. Then, Ember.js can talk to your API, through ember-data.

If you are building a mobile application, this should help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-sqlite-adapter